A question about a proof of "Optimal Control" by R. Vinter
I don't understand the proof of the Proposition 2.3.4. in the book "Optimal Control" by Richard Vinter.

Proposition 2.3.4.: Consider a function $\phi\colon I\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \times\mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ satisfying the following
hypotheses.

$\phi(t,\cdot,u)$ is continuous for each $(t,u)\in I\times\mathbb{R}^{m}$.
$\phi(\cdot,x,\cdot)$ is $\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{B}^{m}$-measurable for each
$x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, for any Lebesgue measurable function
$x\colon I\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the mapping $(t,u)\to \phi(t,x(t),u)$ is
$\mathcal{L}\times\mathcal{B}^{m}$-measurable.


At the begin of the proof, the author consider $\{r_{j}\}$ an ordering of the set of $n$-vectors with rational coefficients. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ define:
$$
\phi_{k}(t,u) := \phi(t,r_{j},u),
$$
where $j$ is chosen such that:
$$
|x(t)-r_{j}| \leq \frac{1}{k}
$$
and
$$
|x(t)-r_{i}| > \frac{1}{k}
$$
for all $i=1,2,\dots,j-1$. These conditions uniquely define $j$ (note that $j$ depend of $t$ and $k$), but I don't understand why. Perhaps it is an argument typical of the real analysis that I cannot see or do not remember, I would appreciate if someone helps me understand that step.
Regards

Are you asking why the above process uniquely defines $j$ as a function of $t,k$?

Yes, and I don't understand why its true the condition

The rationals $\mathbb{Q}^n$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and are countable, so we can write $\mathbb{Q}^n = { r_1, r_2,...}$. Define $j(k,t) =\min { j \in \mathbb{N} \mid |x(t) - r_j| \le {1 \over k} }$. Then $\phi_k(t,u) = \phi(t, r_{j(k,t)}, u)$.
